# How should I batch upload to s3 and insert to MongoDB from nodeJS webserver with a final callback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, amazon-s3, callback

I have a web server that accepts images from client, processes them, upload them to S3, batch-insert the urls to my mongoDB, and lastly sending the json result back to the client.

Working with a single image works as follows:

```
router.post("/upload", function(req, res){
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
        s3.upload({
                Key: filename,
                Bucket: bucketname,
                ACL: "public-read",
                Body: fs.createReadStream(filepath)
         }, function(err, data){
            if(err) //error handle

            Model.collection.insert({"name": "name", "url" : data.Location}, function(err, result){
                if(err) //error handle
                res.json({result: result})
            })
        })
    })
})
```

This works very well as I am simply uploading the file data to s3 -> when done, insert s3's output (url) to database -> when done, send mongo's result as jsonarray to the client.

The issue is - my client html excepts multiple `type=file` input with the same `name=images`, so that i can access them in my form parser as `images[i]`. The above algorithm is repeated `images.length` times. Problem rises when  I have to return the jsonarray result back to the client as I would have to wait for all of the asynchronous S3 upload->mongo insert to finish, and I can't pinpoint how and where the callback would be for this job.

What I've tried are the following:

- Iterate through images, upload them to S3 first, populate an array with the resulting url (`[data.Location]`). Batch insert them to mongoDB and return jsonarray result to client in the call back. This didn't work as mongo insert doesn't wait for S3 upload.
- Iterate through images, upload and insert the images to S3 and mongoDB each iteration. `if (currentIndex = images.length)`, return jsonarray result. This doesn't work accurately as I do not know which images will end last (different size).

How should I design the algorithm to batch upload s3, batch insert to mongo, return result including s3 urls, filename etc back to client as jsonarray?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually solve this kind of problems with Promises, see: [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com).

You could then do a batch upload on S3 using `Promise.all()`, once you get that callback you can batch insert into Mongo, when done, run the final callback. OR, you could do a batch that does both things: `upload->insert to mongo`, and when all of those are done, return final callback. It will depend on your server and on how many files you want to upload at once. You could also use `Promise.map()` with the `concurrency` option set to whatever concurrent tasks you want to run.

Pseudo-code example:

Lets asume that `getFiles`, `uploadFile` and `uploadToMongo` return a `Promise` object.

```
var maxConcurrency =  10;

getFiles()
    .map(function(file){
        return uploadFile(file)
            .then(uploadToMongo) 
    },{concurrency: maxConcurrency})
    .then(function(){
            return finalCallback();
    }).catch(handleError);
```

Example, how to *manually* "promisify* S3:

```
function uploadMyFile(filename, filepath, bucketname) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        s3.upload({
            Key: filename,
            Bucket: bucketname,
            ACL: "public-read",
            Body: fs.createReadStream(filepath)
        }, function(err, data){
            //This err will get to the "catch" statement.
            if (err) return reject(err);
            // Handle success and eventually call:
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

You can use this as:

```
uploadMyFile
        .then(handleSuccess)
        .catch(handleFailure);
```

All nice and pretty!

Comment: Hi. Infact, I have indeed tried bluebird but I didn't get it working well. I followed and had my code identical to [this guide](https://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/s3-batch-upload/). Is the code outdated or something? `var s3 = bluebird.promisifyAll(new aws.S3());` doesn't seem to make any changes and `bluebird.all(uploadToS3, function(data){uploadToMongo})` did not wait for s3 upload to finish, either.

Comment: After a lot of trial and attempt, I reached to a point where I have a map of `bluebird.promisify(uploadToS3())` and `bluebird.all(mapOfUploadToS3(), function(){rest})`. It does upload to S3, but now it never gets to the rest of the functions. I'm suspecting that I need some sort of mechanism to let Promise know that uploadToS3() has finished its job? Am i on the right track?

Comment: Woops, sorry that was `bluebird.join(bluebird.all(mapOfUploadToS3()),function(data){rest});` Sorry about the wordy reply. Thank you so much, in advance!

Comment: I added an example on how you can accomplish that manually, I usually do it that way as I have more control, I can log things, add more logic, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Your assistance really did help me get promises working!! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant get promises to work, you can store the status of your calls in a local variable. You would just break up your calls into 2 functions, a single upload and a bulk upload.

This is dirty code, but you should be able to get the idea:

```
router.post("/upload", function(req, res){
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
        if (err){
            cb(err);
        } else {
            bulkUpload(files, fields, function(err, result){
                if (err){
                    cb(err);
                } else {
                    res.json({result:result});
                }
            })
        }
    })
})

function singleUpload(file, field, cb){
    s3.upload({
            Key: filename,
            Bucket: bucketname,
            ACL: "public-read",
            Body: fs.createReadStream(filepath)
     }, function(err, data){
        if(err)
            cb(err);
        } else {
            Model.collection.insert({"name": "name", "url" : data.Location}, function(err, result){
                if(err){ 
                    cb(err);
                } else {
                    cb(null, result);
                }
            })
        }
    })
}

function bulkUpload (files, fields, cb) {
    var count     = files.length;
    var successes = 0;
    var errors    = 0;

    for (i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
        singleUpload(files[i], fields[i], function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                errors++
                //do something with the error?
            } else {
                successes++
                //do something with the result?
            }

            //when you have worked through all of the files, call the final callback
            if ((successes + errors) >= count) {
                cb(
                    null, 
                    {
                        successes:successes,
                        errors:errors
                    }
                )
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This would not be my recommended method, but another user has already suggested promises. I figure an alternative method would be more helpful.

Good Luck!